# Bevel direction

Tags: bevel

Does anyone have any clue how to control the bevel directions for Blender2.8? Whenever I try to bevel an edge that is connected to another vertical edge, the bevel tend to not go towards x,y,or z axis as shown on the image attached. As shown on the image, the red arrows are going towards the direction that I anticipated, but the green arrow shows how the vertex isn't moving towards the direction I hope for... This wasn't an issue for Blender 2.79. I tried applying transform by pressing ctrl + a and clicked all the options available, but didn't work... [image]

Comment: How could it ? It's a matter of normals and this is broken. You'd better work manualy on your model a little more

Comment: @Yvain The model is actually not that complex. I'm just using the combination of hardops and boxcutter. Even if the model is simple as a box, as long as there is a diagonal edge involved, this issue occurs.

Comment: You should have zero loose vertex, by that I mean that every edges must make a loop (as long as it's possible). Try to connect the vertex that is alone to the ridge is a direct way with ctrl+k.